# Why does this webform uploaded file via ajax throw an error in Drupal 7?

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, redirect, form-api, managed-file

I have a **webform** and **mymodule** which alters it. The webform has a field `stelle` which gets populated based on the **url query**. For instance, if `?stelle=10` the field gets populated by the title of **node with nid 10**. If the query `?stelle` is non-existant or followed by a nid which does not exist (is not of a certain content type) or does not contain a certain string the form will be redirecting to `mynode?stelle=initiativ`. The form has 2 fields to upload files via ajax, works good so far. Here is my code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Altering the form! this will add class to the file upload/ remove buttons
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $conf = mymodule_defaults();

    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_' . $conf['nid']) {
        if (isset($form['submitted']['field1'])) {
            $form['submitted']['field1']['#process'] = array('mymodule_my_file_element_process');
        }

        if (isset($form['submitted']['field2'])) {
            $form['submitted']['field2']['#process'] = array('mymodule_my_file_element_process');
        }

        $nid = $form['#node']->nid;
        $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
            'callback' => 'mymodule_webform_js_submit',
            'wrapper' => 'webform-client-form-' . $nid,
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade',
        );

        $redirect_form = false;
        $maintenance = false;

        if (isset($form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value']) && $form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value'] !== '') {
            $hide_components = array(
                'einleitung_standard',
                'einleitung_initiativ',
            );
            $unhide_components = array();

            if ($form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value'] == '') {
                $redirect_form = true;
            }
            elseif (is_numeric($form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value'])) {
                $nid = $form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value'];
                $node = node_load($nid);

                if ($node === false || (isset($node->type) && $node->type !== 'job')) {
                    $redirect_form = true;
                }
                else {
                    $type = $node->type;
                    if ($type == 'job') {
                        $form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value'] = $node->title;
                        $form['submitted']['stelle']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';
                        $form['submitted']['related']['#value'] = $nid;

                        $unhide_components = array(
                            'einleitung_standard'
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            elseif ($form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value'] == 'initiativ') {
                // unset($form['submitted']['stelle']);
                $form['submitted']['related']['#value'] = 'initiativ';
                $unhide_components = array(
                    'einleitung_initiativ'
                );
            }
        }
        else {
            // $redirect_form = true;
            // this causes an error

        }
```

This is the weird part:

```
        $redirect_form = false;
        $maintenance = false;

        if (isset($form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value']) && $form['submitted']['stelle']['#default_value'] !== '') {
        ...
        else {
            // $redirect_form = true;
            // this causes an error

        }
```

When I active the line to redirect the form when the if condition is false, the button to upload a file via ajax throws an error alert on click (see bottom for error). **To me, this looks like the form alter hook is being called again when the file upload button is clicked** without having my field `stelle` available - is that right? How to fix this?

And now the rest of the module, basically just alterings:

```
        else {
            // $redirect_form = true;
            // this causes an error

        }

        foreach ($unhide_components as $key => $component) {
            if (is_array($component)) {
                foreach ($component as $_key => $_component) {
                    $index = array_search($_component, $hide_components[$key]);
                    if ($index !== false) {
                        unset($hide_components[$key][$index]);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $index = array_search($component, $hide_components);
                if ($index !== false) {
                    unset($hide_components[$index]);
                }   
            }
        }

        // hide
        foreach ($hide_components as $k=>$hc1){
            if (is_array($hc1)) {
                foreach ($hc1 as $hc2) unset($form['submitted'][$k][$hc2]);
            } else {
                unset($form['submitted'][$hc1]);
            }
        }


        if ($redirect_form) drupal_goto('node/'.$conf['nid'], array('query'=>array('stelle'=>'initiativ')), 301);
    }
}

function mymodule_my_file_element_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
    $element = file_managed_file_process($element, $form_state, $form);
    $element['upload_button']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('button'));
    $prefix = '<label class="browse-slave">';
    $prefix .= '<span class="button">' . t('Choose a file') . '</span>';
    $element['upload']['#prefix'] = $prefix;
    $element['upload_button']['#prefix'] = '</label>';


    $element['remove_button']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('button'));
    $element['remove_button']['#prefix'] = '</label>';

    return $element;
}

function mymodule_webform_js_submit($form, $form_state) {
  // define the $sid variable (submission id from webform)
  $sid = $form_state['values']['details']['sid'];
  // if we have a sid then we know the form was properly submitted, otherwise, we'll just return the existing $form array
  if ($sid) {
    // first we have to load up the webform node object
    $node = node_load($form_state['values']['details']['nid']);
    // create an array up with the confirmation message, retreived from the webform node
    $confirmation = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => check_markup($node->webform['confirmation'], $node->webform['confirmation_format'], '', TRUE),
    );
    // return the confirmation message
    return $confirmation;
  }
  else {
    // return the form
    return $form;
  }
}
```

[The AJAX error is something like described here.](https://drupal.org/node/725056) Changing server/php settings didnt help it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form builder (and any hook alters) will be run when a form is validated, which happens on `#ajax` actions.

I like to throw static custom data in `$form['#someProperty']` so that it's available in the build, validate, and submit functions. Something like this should help you:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // ...
  if (isset($_GET['stelle'])) {
    $form['#stelle'] = $_GET['stelle']; // This will always be there.
  } 
  // ...
}
```

Another option would be to throw the `$node` that you load in the form, like `$form['#stelle_node'] = node_load(...)` and obviously *only* do that when the nid is actually available to you, so that you don't overwrite it with empty data when the form builder runs again in the future.

Comment: i will try it out. i removed any redirecting and now it works, but still i am wondering how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

When i was working with ajax in drupal 6 the hash symbol in url or request caused an error everytime..... so i replaced url with this

```
         data.url.replace(/%2523/, '%23');
```